# Is it possible to override the StringRelatedField in DRF?

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have two models (for example comity and members), and members are related to comity using a **StringRelatedField**,

the problem is that when I want to post a new member and link him to a comity, the StringRelatedField is always read_only, so I can't do what I want.

Is there any way I can override a method somewhere so that I'll be able to post normally, or should I go with PrimaryKeyRelatedField and override the to_representation() method ?

Answer (score 2):

> the StringRelatedField is always read_only.

You are likely looking for [`SlugRelatedField`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#slugrelatedfield) which allows the relation to be represented by a string with the constraint that it is unique.